# Error when calling Render method on reporting services 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've moved my web application to a new server, when it calls the render method on the reporting services 2008 web service it brings back the error "Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with an empty response".  It works fine on my development machine. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Many thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft, in their wisdom have completely changed how this works now.  You'll need to add a new reference to some other service at ReportServer/reportexecution2005.asmx.

From here you can create ReportExecutionService object; this contains a Render method you can use.  Don't expect your pain and misery to stop there though, oh no.  The list of arguments it accepts are different too, so you'll need to rethink that as well.

Cheers Microsoft, thanks for keeping our lives simple, and trying to maintain some form a compatibility between release.  As you might have guessed, I've been ripping hair because of this.  I would like to meet the individual who dreamed up this craziness.

Anyway... hope this helps.

Paul